# MySQL selecting more than one id depending on value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on stock control in my system and i have a table for "locations" of stock in a warehouse. This is the location table.

```
id  location_description_id location_key    product_id  qty
6   1                       1               3           25
7   1                       2               4           25
8   1                       3               3           20
```

I'm struggling with getting the location values. For example if there is an order for 40 pieces for product id "3", you can see there is 25 pieces in location_key 1 and 20 pieces in location_key 3

What would be the best way to select the next available location_key when the first one runs out? so in this case the return would be id 6, qty 25 and id 8, qty 15 (totaling my 40)

Comment: Could you try explaining your question better?

Comment: @Tomm basically if i have 100 products in a warehouse split into 2 locations, 50 in "a1" and 50 in "f1" and there is an order of 70 products i would want to return a1,50 and f1,20 to easilly show where to pick the products from in the warehouse

Comment: Hoping this can be done in mySQL

Comment: You give the script or database or whatever the ammounts you want from which database right?

Comment: @Tomm yeah i just wanted someone to show an example of how it could work then i can build it in

Answer (score 1):

Do it on PHP side:

```
$dbLocations = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM location WHERE product_id = 3")->queryAll();

$totalOrder = 50;
$leftOrder = $totalOrder;
$locations = [];

while ($leftOrder >= 0) {
    $location = array_shift($dbLocations);

    if (!empty($location)) {
       $leftOrder -= $location['qty'];
       $locations[] = $location;
    } else {
       throw new Exception('Quantity is too big for locations');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have result from query to select all locations where the ordered product is stored. You can do this in php.

*Edit: edited the function to also return the quantity to pick from every location.*

```
function findLocations($locations, $orderQty)
{
$resultLocs = array();
$i = 0;
$orderRemainQty = $orderQty;

while ($orderRemainQty != 0) {
    $locQty = $locations[$i]['qty'];
    If ($orderRemainQty > $locQty){
        $locations[$i]['pickUpQty'] = $locQty;
        $orderRemainQty -= $locQty;
    } else {
        $locations[$i]['pickUpQty'] = $orderRemainQty;
        $orderRemainQty = 0;
    }
    $resultLocs[] = $locations[$i];
    $i++;
}
return $resultLocs;
```

}

Comment: Oh sorry din`t understand you also need exact quantity you need to pull from every location. Lemme rework the function :)

Comment: Try now. Not so good looking as before but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called OVER (PARTITION BY id) in SQL server which will result id, qty and we can query again to get proper result.

Its hard to get required response in MySQL but below link will help.

-> https://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/

you should be able to generate output like below and from that you can query sum_all>=40 limit 1;

```
id location_key product_key qty sum_all
6  1            3           25  25
8  3            3           20  45
```

Comment: Your link may be invalid in future, please include proper explanation instead of link only.